# How to set a newly created google sheet as the active sheet using v4 api?

Tags: google-sheets

I see that App script allows mimicking user action.
Wondering if setActiveSheet or similar can be done using the v4 apis.

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately this is not possible

There is no respective endpoint incorporated into the Sheets API.

However, if you do not want to use Apps Script because you work in a different programming language - note that you can use the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api).

This allows you to programmatically create, modify and call an Apps Script function - embedded into your exisitng application in a language of your choice.